# Android - Passing value from 1 page to the next

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have my answer, I was calling the text value from outside the button onClick, below is the correct code:

```
    // PAGE 1

    Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            EditText value= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.VALUETOPASS);
            final String VALUE= value.getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(page1.this, page2.class);
        i.putExtra("ARRIVING_FROM", VALUE);
        i.putExtra("TEST", "test");
        startActivity(i);
        }
    }); 

    // PAGE 2

    Intent i = getIntent();
    Bundle b = i.getExtras();
    String newText = b.getString("ARRIVING_FROM")+" "+ b.getString("TEST");
```

Thanks All

Comment: Intent i;
 i.getStringExtra("ARRIVING_FROM") does not help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do `VALUE= value.getText().toString();` inside the onclick handler. The way this is set up, it will take the text from the textview at the very start (where it is empty) and pass this empty string to the 2nd intent.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the text from the textfield into `VALUE` right at the start before the user has had a chance to enter anything. Read the data when you want to use it, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("ARRIVING_FROM");

String test = getIntent().getStringExtra("TEST");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value from the textbox inside the onClick handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get textView values in the onclick, not before. Like this:

```
// PAGE 1
Button submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){

    EditText value= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.VALUETOPASS);
    final String VALUE= value.getText().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent(page1.this, page2.class);
    i.putExtra("ARRIVING_FROM", VALUE);
    i.putExtra("TEST", "test");
    startActivity(i);
    }
});
```